# How do I change image B's src to Image A's src when Image A is clicked with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Goal: When image A is clicked that same image appears at the bottom of the page. Needs to work for more than one image.

When image A is clicked I need image B to now have the same src as image A.
Or to Generate a copy of the clicked image. 
This should also be able to work for several pictures.

So for example if I clicked 5 images (Image A-01, A-02, A-03, A-04, A-05) on the screen....

At the bottom of the page there should be those 5 images

I've tried
HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/150">
<img id="new" src="http://placehold.it/200">
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $("#myImage").click(function() {
    $("#new").attr("src","http://placehold.it/150")
    });
});
```

Which works to replace one image but I need the same code to work for multiple image clicks.

Comment: can you please post some code you have tried?

Comment: Added some code I've tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another proposal with an event listener.

```js
var imgCount = 5,
    i;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById('img' + i).addEventListener('click', setImg('img' + i), false);
}

function setImg(id) {
    return function () {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        if (imgCount) {
            imgCount--;
            img.src = document.getElementById(id).src;
            document.getElementById('footer').appendChild(img);
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/1" />
<img id="img2" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/2" />
<img id="img3" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/3" />
<img id="img4" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/4" />
<img id="img5" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/city/5" />
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Cool. Hmm. The id I'm using on my pictures is "card" What would I need to change to make it run?

Comment: replace `img` with `card`.

Comment: Cant quite get it to work. Which "img" tags above would I need to change?

Comment: i am using `img1` to `img5` as id of the image elements. in the loop for the event listener, i use `'img' + i` as indicator for the id. if you want `card1` to `card5`, then update the two places with the new string.

Comment: Ah ha! Finally got it to work! :) Thanks so much! 

One final question. I need to be able to display the new images next to a text box. For example:

Image - Text Box
Image - Text Box
Image - Text Box

How would you recommend going about that?

Thank you again!!!

Comment: you can use div or a span and append then the image to it, like above with all images, then only with one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110028/discussion-between-andrewleonardi-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out

```js
function changeSrc(id){
document.getElementById('footer').src = document.getElementById(id).src;  
}
```

```html
<img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" height="200" width="auto" id="img1" onclick="changeSrc(this.id)"/>
<img src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/uk-electronics/product_content/Nikon/ECS-NK1308141-B00ECGX8FM-2L-1024w683q85s10-BKEH_London_Paris__0316.jpg" height="200" width="auto" id="img2" class="image" onclick="changeSrc(this.id)"/>
<img src="" height="200" width="auto" id="footer" class="image" />
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! So instead of the footer I'm needing to organize the generated images in column so I'll need to be able to choose the generated image's location specifically. Advise? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg" class="a">
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg" class="a">
<img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/7.jpg" class="a">
<br>
<div id="sectionB">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/48" class="b">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/48" class="b">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/48" class="b">
</div>
<br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

===

```
$(function() {
  $('.a').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    var index = $(this).index();

    $('.b').eq(index).attr('src', img);
  })

  $('#reset').click(function(){
    $('.b').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/48');
  })
})
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/j359yfor/

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome. For some reason however when I apply this to my code it's only updating the first image. Any idea why that would be?